# How can I exclude reading settings.xml from mavens .m2 folder

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

does anyone knows how can I use the default maven settings and not the one which is defined in .m2/settings.xml, as this file has some other configurations which aren't suiting this project? I cloned a simple SpringBoot project, but can't find a solution of how to tell the project to not look on those settings from .m2/ and use the default ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a second `settings.xml` (e.g. named `second-settings.xml`) that is right for your project and use it with `-s second-settings.xml` on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ you can override the settings file used by the maven plugin under **Settings** > **Build, Execution, Deployment** > **Build Tools** > **Maven**